# Trying to use fetch_20newsgroups

Tags: python-3.x, windows, anaconda3

I am in the process of learning Python and have the following problem with fetching the 20newwsgroups data in the this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import *

categories = ['comp_graphics', 'misc_foresale',
             'rec.autos', 'sci.space']

twenty_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                                 categories=categories,
                                 shuffle=True,
                                 random_state=42)

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(
    twenty_train.data)

print(X_train_counts)
print("BOW shape:", X_train_counts.shape)
caltech_idx = count_vect.vocabulary_['caltech']
print('"Caltech": %i' % X_train_counts[0, caltech_idx])
```

The version of scikit learn i have is 1.0.2, python version 3.7.9. although I do have a copy of Python 3.10 installed as well

Comment: What's your problem?  Paste your error and what you expect to happen.

Comment: I get a blank response when I am expecting the prints to return details